# Analysis of text using Gunning Fox index

Tags: python, nlp, stop-words

While doing Analysis of readability using Gunning Fox index-. I have to calculate following values

1. Average Sentence Length = the number of words / the number of sentences
2. Percentage of Complex words = the number of complex words / the number of words
3. Fog Index = 0.4 * (Average Sentence Length + Percentage of Complex words)

I want to know whether the number of words  will be calculated after removing duplicates and stop words i.e. after cleaning  or just the total no of words in the text without removing any words or cleaning?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't do any cleaning or 'stop-word' removal.

You are trying to calculate how easy it is to read the text. Stop words are only relevant for old-style information retrieval. Also, do not remove duplicates. Process the text as-is, otherwise the result will be wrong.

If you were to remove stopwords, the text would be more difficult to read, as effectively a lot of short (ie "easy") words will have been removed.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have one more doubt . Suppose I want to count the percentage of complex words. Do I have to count from unfiltered text or filtered/clean text beacause if there are duplicate words then the count may increase.

Comment: @AmanVerma You are looking at the text as a whole, not the vocabulary. An English dictionary is different in difficulty from a novel. So yes, do count duplicates, and do _not_ filter the text or remove words.

Comment: One more doubt that I have is if a negative word is repeated 3 times in the text. For eg- 'fraud' word comes three times in the text then whether I will count it one time only or its no of occurrences while counting total neg words in the text.

Comment: @AmanVerma "negative" has got nothing to do with the Fog index.

Comment: Yes Oliver. But I have to count them for another purpose.